# Removing Android fragments permanently

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm writing an instant messaging application which uses a Fragment for each conversation, and the user can swipe sideways to move between conversations.

Despite intensive looking at similar questions on Stackoverflow I'm still have problems with removing a Fragment when the user leaves a conversation.

For example, let's say they're in conversations (and Fragments) A, B, and C. When B is closed code changes the screen to Fragment A. That's fine, but when they then scroll right to get conversation C, the app crashes with the following.

Can anyone help? The relevant part of the Fragment creation and delete code is below. Thank you.

*Crash details*

```
>D/AndroidRuntime( 9677): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 9677): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41039300)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677): java.lang.NullPointerException
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:819)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>E/AndroidRuntime( 9677):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*Relevant code:*

```
public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
.... unrelated code...
private FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
private ConversationsAdapter adapter = new ConversationsAdapter( manager );
.... unrelated code...

class ConversationsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public ConversationsAdapter( FragmentManager manager ) {
                super( manager );
                fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        }

        public void addItem()
        {
                Fragment item = new ConversationFragment();
                fragments.add( item );
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeItem( int position ) {
                Fragment item = adapter.getItem( position );

                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.setTransition( FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE );
                transaction.remove( item );
                transaction.commit();

                fragments.remove( position );
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
                pager.setCurrentItem( position - 1 );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can remove fragment programmatically using following code

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack("NameofBackstack",
FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```